# Como resolver o erro java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: java, oracle, sqldeveloper

Estou tentando instalar o [sqldeveloper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) e [datamodeler](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/overview/index.html) no meu Fedora 20 e estou tendo problema com seguinte erro:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: localdomain: localdomain: Name or service not known
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1473)
        at org.netbeans.CLIHandler$2.run(CLIHandler.java:667)
        at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1432)
        at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2044)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: localdomain: Name or service not known
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1293)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1469)
        ... 3 more
```

Estou com Java 1.7.0_51 instalado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esse erro ocorre porque a resolução de nomes de domínios do Java esta querendo o nome do host.

Para resolver use:

```
HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier() {
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {  
        return true;
    }
};
```

Assim a resolução do nome será ignorada. Coloque esse código antes antes da chamada de conexão seja RMI, Socket ou Webservice.

Answer (score 5):

Descobri como resolver o bug.

No caso o aplicativo está iniciando um host utilizando o nome da máquina `localdomain` e tentando acessa-la pelo nome, como este nome não tem nenhum IP relacionado ele está dando este erro.

Eu editei o arquivo `/etc/hosts` e adicionei a seguinte linha:

```
127.0.0.1    localdomain
```

Isso foi suficiente pra ele reconhecer o nome do domínio e encontra-lo, fazendo com que ambas as aplicações parem de dar erro.

Comment: Valeu pela dica Gabriel, estava com o mesmo problema cara!

Comment: Value @Gabriel Gartz Me ajudou tb.